# improving checking Not null Condition

Tags: java, string, null

I'm trying to put not null check to this below return statement below in java file. The property file i have `TEMP_CONFIG.properties` and it is containing values like: `EMP_DEP.DEVL=DEV Employee : DEV`. Here I am getting the value of the property using `infoType.trim()`. Here I have to check the null condition of this.

```
    public String buildInfo(String empId,String infoType) throws IOException{   
        return EmpProperties.getProperty("/TEMP_CONFIG.properties", "EMP_DEP."+infoType.trim());
}
```

Here I have to do null check and just return the original infoType value if it is null.
The infoType is `DEVL` from the above property.

Need some suggestion to check not null.

Comment: So , you don't know how to write a if condition?

Comment: what will be the output if null

Comment: `Suggestion` : Check `!= null`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ :) i know..searching for better idea..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String result = EmpProperties.getProperty(...)
if (result != null) return result else return infoType;
```

Something like this?

Comment: Better we can check both null and empty in the above condition. as: `String result = EmpProperties.getProperty("/TEMP_CONFIG.properties", "EMP_DEP."+infoType.trim()); if(infoType == null || infoType.equals("")){ result=infoType;} return result;`

Comment: The question was how to check for null, not how to check if it is empty or null. If the latter is required, then your additions are needed. As the question is posed however, my answer does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

If the infoType can be null

```
return EmpProperties.getProperty("/TEMP_CONFIG.properties", "EMP_DEP."+(infoType != null ? infoType.trim() : ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done using ternary opertor.

```
public String buildInfo(String empId,String infoType) throws IOException{   
    return EmpProperties.getProperty("/TEMP_CONFIG.properties", "EMP_DEP."+(infoType.trim() == null ? "" : infoType.trim()));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public String buildInfo(String empId,String infoType) throws IOException {   
    String s = EmpProperties.getProperty("/TEMP_CONFIG.properties", "EMP_DEP."+infoType.trim());

    if(s == null) {

       s = infoType;

    }
    return s;
}
```

Please note my code is in a basic form lol. It is very possible using a "? :" setup. Its a very simple if statement...

Comment: don't you think you need to return s instead of infotype!

Comment: You saw nothing! LOL Classic programming mistake right there.

Comment: you can check with if(s == null ||s.equals("")) method also.. but given +1